# How to edit EFI file path?

Tags: path, efi

How do I change the *.EFI file path from

```
\EFI\Loader1\DCSBOOT.EFI
```

to

```
\EFI\Loader2\DCSBOOT.EFI
```

? I've tried tools like EasyUEFI and VisualBCD. But there were no options to do that. Beside that I have no ideo how to start. I can't edit it like regular file systems (or am I wrong?).

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done prior to coming here to ask?

Comment: I've tried tools like EasyUEFI and VisualBCD. But there were no options to do that. Beside that I have no ideo how to start. I can't edit it like regular file systems (or am I wrong?).

Comment: Please use the EDIT button to add this and any other relevant and contextual information to the question itself. This will make your question better and more clear and help those with answers find it.

Comment: I've done that.

Comment: `EasyUEFI` looks like an appropriate tool for the job. After moving the file. Is that perhaps where you’re stuck? Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes I'm on windows. But I can't see where I can change the path...